# What's the difference between Modify and All privileges on a Snowflake schema?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

According to Snowflake, "Modify: Enables altering any settings of a schema." while "All: Grants all privileges, except OWNERSHIP, on a schema.".  I don't understand the effective difference based on their descriptions.

[Snowflake Schema Privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#schema-privileges)

Answer (score 1):

I read it as `MODIFY` allows you to run the commands in the [ALTER SCHEMA](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-schema.html#alter-schema) space, thus set something like `DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS = <num>`

where-as the `CREATE TABLE` permission does not allow setting those parameters, and `MODIFY` alone does not allow you to create tables.

Where-as `ALL [ PRIVILEGES ]` allows you both alter the schema AND create tables. So it's not so much the different between Modify and All but Modify and/or other privileges and ALL which is the set of them (excluding ownership)

Answer (score 0):

The **MODIFY** schema privileges enables you to modify the schema settings such as DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS, DEFAULT_DDL_COLLATION, COMMENT. Please check alter schema command:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-schema.html

Please note that, you also need to have USAGE privilege on the schema and the database to modify any settings of the schema.

When you grant **ALL** privileges on a schema, the user can select the schema, modify its settings, create objects on that schema (I assume the user also has USAGE privilege on the database).